# Golang print map inside map generated by json.NewDecoder

Tags: go

I'm using [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874115/773263) to fetch some json from an api:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   resp, err := http.Get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=1234")
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }
   var generic map[string]interface{}
   err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&generic)
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }
   fmt.Println(generic)
}
```

It's working, I have a map of the json stored in the `generic` variable.

When I print with:

```
fmt.Println(generic["city"])
```

I get back:

```
map[id:524901 name:Moscow coord:map[lon:37.615555 lat:55.75222] country:RU population:0 sys:map[population:0]]
```

Now I want to access the city name. I'm trying the following:

```
fmt.Println(generic["city"]["name"])
```

And I get error:

> muxTest/router.go:30: invalid operation: generic["city"]["name"] (type
>   interface {} does not support indexing)

Also tried `generic["city"].name` which didn't work.

How can I access the city name value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `interface{}` of your `map[string]interface{}` to something more useful.  In this case a `map[string]interface{}` again since `city` is itself a map.  You can't convert it to anything else because the `coord` is a map too, so converting city to a `map[string]string` isn't possible.

https://play.golang.org/p/bGsYLnSAK4